# Get byte data from a file

Tags: vb.net

I am using this little function to get the byte data from a file but sometimes I get errors maybe bad file or bad code or file in use?

```
        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As System.IO.BinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim data() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))
        br.Close()
        fs.Close()
        Return data
```

Comment: You've asked several questions recently, and I know of at least one that has been closed. Instead of shotgunning a bunch of questions out there - why don't you focus on one or two, and try to write really good, well thought-out questions that show a) you've put a lot of effort into the problems, and b) you've put a lot of work into helping us *help you*.

Comment: are you here to troll new users or to help?

Comment: >shotgunning a bunch of questions out there...
3 questions per day? wow

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that lashing out at experienced members who are trying to help you become a better developer is probably *not* the way to go about things. Would you ask a senior developer at your company that same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a small enough file that you want all the bytes in memory in an array, the easiest way to do it is:

```
Dim data() as Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
```

Comment: 5MB will be a pretty big array, so it all depends on what you're doing with it. Most file tasks you only need to read a small amount of the file at a time, using a buffer. You can find lots of examples online on how to use a small buffer, so you only have a few thousand bytes at a time in memory.